# Active Directory password expiration - changing in staggered groups

Tags: windows, passwords, group-policy

I can't test this without causing problems for a lot of people.  I'd like to enable on a Group Policy for password expiration for my hundreds of Active Directory users, but avoid having a Hell Day for everyone.

Let's say most users have 100+ days since password change.  If I set Group Policy now so that passwords expire after 100 days, I expect most will be blocked immediately.  But I'd like to have a cohort change password today, and another cohort change password next week, etc.  Then, after the compliant have changed passwords and everyone is duly notified, I can enable the Group Policy.

Does AD's password expiration depend on the creation of the rule in Group Policy?  Will everyone's trigger on the same day later?  Or staggered in the cohorts I mentioned?

Comment: You should be able to with a PowerShell script, determine when the password was changed, for a given user.  You can then determine, how many days ago this was, and confine any changes to the parameters you set.  What have you tried?  You can then at any point in time you decide change the policy

Comment: This isn't an answer, but be aware that the latest revision of NIST 800-63b explicitly advises against regular password changes - because it compels people to use predictable mnemonic strategies. For example, if passwords must be changed every 90 days and standard complexity is required, the most common pattern is "[Season][YYYY]!" (Spring2019!, Summer2019!, etc.) For obvious reasons, password crackers cut through these like a hot knife through butter - and the NIST authors have caught on to that fact. Instead, encourage random passphrases, and rotate when needed (departures, compromise, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your comments and the answer below.  Active Directory users have a field with the date the password was last set.  The system calculates "Does the current user's password need to be reset?" comparing that field and the current date.  As long as system clocks are working, it's fine.  I'll proceed with scripts as suggested.  Probably like these : https://www.oxfordsbsguy.com/2013/11/25/powershell-get-aduser-to-retrieve-password-last-set-and-expiry-information/

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use AD password expiration to do this initially.

Instead, use powershell, or even AD Users and Computers to flag a certain subset of users to change their password at next logon.

If you use AD Users and Computers you can multi-select users, then right-click and set properties in bulk.

If you use powershell, you could additionally check when the last time the password was changed and if over a certain time, flag the account for a password change.

Once everyone is updated, like you said, enable the group policy to set password expiration.

In powershell, you’ll use a combination of `get-aduser` and `set-aduser` to accomplish this task.